# Calculating a percentage of 2 columns in my SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get a percentage of two columns in SQL, but for some reason the division part of the equation is not happening?

I'm very new to this, but excited to learn. Thank you for your help!

```
SELECT      
    Jaar,
    SUM(Bedrag) AS 'Totaal te innen contributie',
    (SELECT SUM(Bedrag) 
     FROM Betaling 
     WHERE Jaar = Contributie.Jaar) AS 'Totaal geïnde contributie',
    CAST((SUM(Bedrag) / (SELECT SUM(Bedrag) 
                         FROM Betaling 
                         WHERE Jaar = Contributie.Jaar) * 100) AS numeric(7,2)) AS 'percentage beta' 
FROM    
    Contributie 
GROUP BY    
    Jaar
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server) ?

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Comment: The SQL you've posted is not valid. Please post sample data, the desired output, and your actual effort to solve the problem yourself. When you [edit] to do so, you can also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using.

Comment: @KenWhite Agree about the data...but there actually is effort (well, I _think_ I was able to give a correct query based on what I saw above :-) ).

Comment: Using a string constant as a column alias is non-standard SQL (invalid according to the SQL standard). So which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: You may have been able to give a correct answer, but the question doesn't have much value to future users here without a clear problem statement. Answering without the poster editing first removes all incentive for them to do so (as you can see).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can approach this using a join:

```
SELECT      
    c.Jaar,
    SUM(c.Bedrag) AS 'Totaal te innen contributie',
    b.bedrag_sum AS 'Totaal geïnde contributie',
    100.0 * SUM(c.Bedrag) / b.bedrag_sum AS 'percentage beta'
FROM Contributie c
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Jaar, SUM(Bedrag) AS bedrag_sum
    FROM Betaling
    GROUP BY Jaar
) b
    ON c.Jaar = b.Jaar
GROUP BY
    c.Jaar;
```

The subquery aliased as `b` replaces the correlated subqueries you had in the select clause.

Comment: Although it should be a `left join` to match the original query.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I'm doing this in Microsoft SQL manager studio for anyone who asked and am a complete beginner.